# How to edit a Wordpress project(files) website?

Tags: contextual-help

I have project files of the Wordpress website on my computer but I don't know how to edit it on Wordpress. We don't have the Wordpress account that was used to develop the Wordpress website. Is it still possible to make an update on this project?

Comment: What exactly do you have, and where is the site you're hoping to update hosted? The most important bits are the wp-content/uploads folder and the database, but there may also be custom or premium plugins and themes that you'd need. But if you have a complete copy of the site then yes you can re-upload it somewhere, or run it locally, and make changes in the admin area. If the site is live somewhere else and you want to edit that you'll need to log into that to change it there, or if you don't have a working login but have access to the live copy of the database or files you can make a login.

Comment: @Rup it is hosted in us.cloudlogin.co, we have access to it but we don't have access to the Wordpress account that was used to develop the site. So we have a complete copy of the site.

Comment: OK. If you want to change the hosted version of the site you'll need to get an admin login to it - the copy of the site won't help. You'll have to ask an existing admin to create you an account. (I guess if you do have a copy of the database then you could try and crack the password hashes in there, but that's very unlikely to work unless someone deliberately chose a weak password: your best option is to ask.)

Comment: If you already have admin access then that's probably all you need - you don't need the WordPress account that developed the site in the first place (do you mean a WordPress.com account?). Or do you mean the account with the hosting provider? If you don't have that then you may not have access to site logs, but as long as everything's running fine that shouldn't matter; or unless your site is running without permission to write to its own files, and then you'd need an FTP login or similar to perform updates - is that the problem?